# Assign hardware to different users on windows server 2003

Tags: networking, port, virtualization

I have this software that has port conflicts on my windows 2003 server. So my solution is to use Virtual network card from http://www.ntkernel.com/w&p.php?id=32 . I have 10 users per server, how do I install each Virtual card separately for each user while still has my real network card working so each user have network access to the outside?

Answer (score 2):

This is a really weird way of going about this to be honest. The modern way of dividing servers up in this manner is via virtualisation, where each customer would get an entirely separate VM and you could simply create ten VLANs, trunk them all together down a team of NICs to your router and have the router/firewall separate them. It would certainly be more supportable than basing your entire architecture around a piece of free unsupported code.